# How can I change the url of a media file?

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way to change the url of for example
http://www.mywpsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/mailsignature.png
to
http://www.mywpsite.com/mail/mailsignature.png?

Comment: A simple way it to add a 301 redirect to your file with a plugin like this one https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to your website via ftp as described [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_FileZilla). You can then access and alter the folder structure on your website as you like.

Comment: Adding a "mail" directory in the same directory as index.php worked perfectly. Thank you!